# Should custom elements handle game logic

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

*I'm currently programming Solitaire in Javascript and I use custom elements for cards and also stacks which makes styling a lot easier:*

```
<card-stack id="pile3" card-offset="1px">
  <playing-card unrevealed></playing-card>
  <playing-card rank="queen" suit="diamonds"></playing-card>
  <playing-card rank="jack" suit="spades"></playing-card>
</card-stack>
```

Now I need to check for example if the user is allowed to add a card to a stack.
Should this (generally) be done by the element with a method like `foo.addCard(bar)` which then would return a boolean whether it was successful or not or would this be an abuse of custom elements and I should check inside my main script what the last child of a stack is and so on?

Comment: Personally I think it might be a better idea to put an `addCard` function in like the card stack or main application. This would mean that it allows you to keep a more OOP design. I think any specific card info should be handled with `card-stack` and the main script interacts with the `card-stack`

Comment: @Metthew In my main script I would have an object-oriented design anyways

Comment: sorry I meant that the `card-stack` holds everything to do with the `cards` and should be the only class handling the `cards` directly and the rest of your application only deals specifically with the `card-stack` for interaction with `cards`.

Comment: It's not an abuse and in this case the use of a method seems a good idea.